# Why do i get this error in android studio when i set a background image

Tags: android, android-studio, background

> I want to set a background image to my project in android studio and whenever i set a background i keep getting this error the name of the file is xxx.jpg

Is there any other way to set a background image in android studio or is there anything wrong with the format once i remove the background image it works but i really need to set a background image since i am hoping to publish this in the store

I have gotten this error multiple times and with multiple images! [This is the error i am getting all the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fCyw.png)

```
     public static final class drawable {
                        public static final int 2=0x7f020000;
            //i get the error here^ (2=0x7f020000;)
                        public static final int abc_ab_share_pack_holo_dark=0x7f020001;
                        public static final int abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light=0x7f020002;
                        public static final int abc_btn_check_material=0x7f020003;
                        public static final int abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f020004;
                        public static final int abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015=0x7f020005;
                        public static final int abc_btn_radio_material=0x7f020006;
                        public static final int abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f020007;
                        public static final int abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015=0x7f020008;
                        public static final int abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001=0x7f020009;
                        public static final int abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012=0x7f02000a;
                        public static final int abc_cab_background_internal_bg=0x7f02000b;
                        public static final int abc_cab_background_top_material=0x7f02000c;
                        public static final int abc_cab_background_top_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02000d;
                        public static final int abc_edit_text_material=0x7f02000e;
                        public static final int abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha=0x7f02000f;
                        public static final int abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020010;
                        public static final int abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020011;
                        public static final int abc_ic_go_search_api_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020012;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha=0x7f020013;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020014;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020015;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha=0x7f020016;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020017;
                        public static final int abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020018;
                        public static final int abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020019;
                        public static final int abc_ic_voice_search_api_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02001a;
                        public static final int abc_item_background_holo_dark=0x7f02001b;
                        public static final int abc_item_background_holo_light=0x7f02001c;
                        public static final int abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02001d;
                        public static final int abc_list_focused_holo=0x7f02001e;
                        public static final int abc_list_longpressed_holo=0x7f02001f;
                        public static final int abc_list_pressed_holo_dark=0x7f020020;
                        public static final int abc_list_pressed_holo_light=0x7f020021;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_dark=0x7f020022;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light=0x7f020023;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_dark=0x7f020024;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light=0x7f020025;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_holo_dark=0x7f020026;
                        public static final int abc_list_selector_holo_light=0x7f020027;
                        public static final int abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult=0x7f020028;
                        public static final int abc_popup_background_mtrl_mult=0x7f020029;
                        public static final int abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha=0x7f02002a;
                        public static final int abc_switch_thumb_material=0x7f02002b;
                        public static final int abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02002c;
                        public static final int abc_tab_indicator_material=0x7f02002d;
                        public static final int abc_tab_indicator_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02002e;
                        public static final int abc_textfield_activated_mtrl_alpha=0x7f02002f;
                        public static final int abc_textfield_default_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020030;
                        public static final int abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020031;
                        public static final int abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020032;
                        public static final int abc_textfield_search_material=0x7f020033;
                        public static final int buttonshape=0x7f020034;
                        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020035;
                        public static final int xxx=0x7f020036;
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a `drawable` called `2.png`. All the content of `res/` is translated in `R.java`, and the file's name is used as variable name. The system assign to this variable an int, that you use to reference your resource at runtime.  Since in java you can't use `2` as variable name, you are getting this compile-time error. Rename the file in a way that fulfill the java [rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for the names of the variables